# C# Adding textboxes when tabs are created

Tags: c#, tabs, inputbox

I have a tab control on my form.  I prompt the user through user input (using the Visual Basic library) how many pockets does the header have.  The number in the textbox generates that many number of tabs.

**Question**

How do I add textboxes when new tabs are generated?  Since the number is unknown until I tell it, it wouldn't make sense to just add textboxes to the designer for example.

**What I have**

```
 private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("How many pockets does the header have?", "Pocket Count", "",-1,-1);
            for (int i = 1; i < Convert.ToInt32(input) + 1; i++)
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Pocket" + i);
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Name = tabControl1.Name;


            }
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Next");
        }
```

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: Add always the textboxes, just make them not visible when the tab is not active !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tab Selecting Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):This explains the Tab Selecting Event, you can then use this to dynamically generate the textbox you need on the tab that is being selected.

[How to dynamically add a textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287574%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): This explains how to add a control at runtime and even provides a textbox example.

If you take both of these articles together you *might* end up with something like the below, though you will definitely want to tailor this to your specific application

```
private void TabControl1_Selecting(Object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) 
{

    TextBox dynamictextbox = new TextBox();
    dynamictextbox.Text = "(Enter some text)";
    dynamictextbox.ID = "dynamictextbox";
    (TabControl)sender.controls.Add(dynamictextbox)
}

}
```

This isn't meant to be a complete example but to illustrate how it might work. In your case you will have to wire up the Selecting event in code for each dynamic tab

Answer (score 0):

Get the current TabPage and add the textbox to the tabpage.

```
TabPage current = tabControl1.TabPages[i-1];
current.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Or in 1 statement:

```
tabControl1.TabPages[i-1].Controls.Add(txt);
```